# Link standard Opportunity object to Custom Account Object

Tags: custom

We are a wholesaler and need to track sales activity between our resellers and their customers. We will be using the standard account object to create a customer account record and new opportunities for that customer are then recorded in the opportunities section of account record. Standard stuff. We want to also create a custom account object using IDE to create a record for resellers associated with the transaction just described and have that same opportunity also recorded in the opportunity section of the resellers custom account record. So, two account records, one standard for the customer and one custom for the reseller. One opportunity recorded in the opportunity section of both account types. Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this, specifically? Would appreciate it if you could provide the code.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like you would need code for this at all (nor the IDE), this can be handled with basic configuration. A lookup to the reseller object from `Opportunity` would suffice.

Your reseller object could either be a custom object or you could enable `RecordTypes` on your standard `Account` object and have one `RecordType` for `Customer` account types and one for `Reseller` account types.

It sounds like option #2, creating record types, would work best for you here but you will need to investigate pros/cons there - the standard Account object provides many benefits out of the box that you probably shouldn't try to recreate to support your Reseller accounts with a custom object.

On the custom field (`Reseller`) that you will create on `Opportunity` looking up to either the `Account` object or a custom object, I would probably name the lookup relationship and the related list `Reseller Opportunities` to differentiate it from the standard Opportunity list that may be shown on the page layout.

Comment: I'll give it shot and let you know what happens. One question, will I be able to report on both account types and the opportunities associated with each? In other words, Reseller>Customer Accounts>Customer Opportunities and Customer Accounts>Opportunities>Reseller

Comment: i strongly agree with Mark that option 2 will lead to better outcomes in the long run; reporting is much much easier

Comment: @JORT The short answer is almost certainly yes. Though really you should fire up a sandbox or a dev org, set up the recordtypes on `Account`, create the custom field on `Opportunity`, create a few records and reports and test it out and come back with any other questions you need answered.

Comment: Hey Mark, The record types work great! We have one Account page layout for the Customer and one for the Reseller. We included the standard Account Record Type field in each record that automatically identifies each record respectively. In the Opportunity record in the Opportunity Detail section the left column is Customer Account data and the right column is Reseller data. Each column Account Name has a lookup filter that searches on the respective record types. As long as the Account Records are created prior to creating a new Opportunity there are no issues. Here's where we hit a problem:

Comment: If the Account Record does not exist when I click the lookup next to the Customer Account Name field it looks for the Customer name, which doesn't exist, I click New and the editing page opens and let's me create a new Customer Account record. No problems. Then I click the lookup filter next to the Reseller Account name, it searches the Reseller records and of course it's not there because it doesn't exist yet. I click New, fill in the Reseller info and click save. Then when I try to save the Opportunity an error message fires and it won't accept the Reseller Account name. When I cancel the

Comment: transaction, of course it didn't create a Reseller record, but also, it replaced the Customer Account Name in the Customer record with the Reseller name I tried creating. I'm assuming it's because they're both using Account Name and the system doesn't know which Record Type to map to. Is there any way to have the Account Name for the Customer create a Customer Account Record (which it already does) and the new Reseller Account Name create a Reseller Account Record?

Comment: Hey Mark, I'm back again. Figured out what the issue is. So, when we're creating a new Opportunity, do the Customer lookup, the Account Record doesn't exist, so you click New and create the Customer Account Record. Herein lies the problem, when you go the right column and go through the same process it is automatically defaulting to the Customer Record Type, which you just created for that Opportunity and a Customer Account Name is over in the left column creating the conflict and the error message. SO again, my question is the same, although now I know a bit more about what happening:

Comment: Is there any way to set things so when you do that Reseller lookup and click New to create the Reseller Account Record the system will know to create a Reseller Account Record based on the lookup you just did, rather than just defaulting to the first Record Type in the Record Type list, which in this case is the Customer Account Record Type?